# Rails - How to render an image if a field is populated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application a user can say they have completed a piece of homework.

A field "completed_on" is populated with the date the homework was completed. If not completed the field is blank.

I would like to show a tick if the homework is completed or an x if the homework is not completed.

The column "completed_on" is located in a table called homework_students.

```
class Homework < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :homework_students, :class_name => 'HomeworkStudent'


class HomeworkStudent < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :homework, :class_name => 'Homework'
```

I have tried the following which does not work for me:

In my model:

```
def getCompletion
      homework_students.where("completed_on is not null")
end
```

View:

```
<% if homework.getCompletion %><%= image_tag "fi-check.svg", class: "homework_student_complete" %><% else %><%= image_tag "fi-x.svg", class: "homework_student_complete" %><% end %>
```

I also tried this:

Model

```
def completed?
    !homework.homework_student.completed_on.blank?
end
```

View

```
<% if homework.completed? %>
<%= image_tag "fi-check.svg", class: "homework_student_complete" %><% else %><%= image_tag "fi-x.svg", class: "homework_student_complete" %><% end %>
```

Appreciate any guidance.

UPDATE

This works:

```
def completed?
      homework_students.where("completed_on is not null").length == 0 
    end

<% @homeworks.each do |homework| %>
...
 <td height="1" class="text-center"><% if homework.completed? %>
  <%= image_tag "fi-check.svg", class: "homework_student_complete" %>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag "fi-x.svg", class: "homework_student_complete" %>
<% end %></td>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: That `image_tag` section should only render if the `if` condition evaluates as true. Maybe put in `<%= homework.completed? %>` as a diagnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your query can be an ActiveRecord::Relation or an empty array and on both cases the if statement evaluates to true. Try changing your query to:

```
def completion
      homework_students.where("completed_on is null").length == 0 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The return type of your `getCompletion` method is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. You are then asking if this relation exists by placing this inside a conditional. This will always be `true`, even if the relation contains an empty data set (e.g. `[]`), because an empty Array is truthy.

You should be expecting `getCompletion` to return a collection of `HomeworkStudent` records. If you are wanting to show a tick, or an 'x' only if all students have completed the homework, then you need an aggregate method to check something about all of the records (if there are any, or none, etc). Try do something like:

```
# app/models/homework.rb

def completed?
  homework_students.where("completed_on is null").none?
end


# in the view

<% if homework.completed? %>
  <%= image_tag "fi-check.svg", class: "homework_student_complete" %>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag "fi-x.svg", class: "homework_student_complete" %>
<% end %>
```

More information on ActiveRecord::Relation methods at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-none-3F

Comment: @Co2 Use of `none?` method addressed by Ben seems more elegant ;-)

Answer (score -1):

your method get_completion is not returning anything. Try this

```
@homework_student = homework_students.where("completed_on is not null")
return @homework_student
```

may be it works. Also make sure that the completed_on is not null works correctly.

Comment: In Ruby, the last statement in a method is returned automatically. You basically took @Co2's code and made it do the same thing, but with more verbose code. And even if you were correct in the idea, there is no reason to store the value in an instance method like that.

Comment: ya, right. Sorry mate. Well, the above answers should already help out a bit. ..no time, sorry.